# I got this error "Cannot read property RDF of null" for this part of code

Tags: node.js

```
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
```

```js
   

    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
          body = JSON.parse(body);
          // logic used to compare search results with the input from user
          // console.log(!body.query.results.RDF.item['about'])
          if (!body.query.results.RDF.item) {
            craig = "No results found. Try again.";
          } else {
           results = body.query.results.RDF.item[0]['about']
             craig = '<a href ="'+results+'">'+results+'</a>'
           }
           // pass back the results to client side
          res.send(craig);
         });
        
        });
```

```
});
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is easy to diagnose; the **body.query.results** returned is null. Take a look at the **request** function and figure out why the **body.query** doesn't have the results property you're looking for.

Comment: as I am new to Node ,i follow this tuto  http://mherman.org/blog/2013/10/20/handling-ajax-calls-with-node-dot-js-and-express-scraping-craigslist/#.VbrugPl_Oko                                                But it doesn't work for me !

Comment: Since you're new to node it's imperative that you **don't** simply type everything in and hit "go"... make sure that you 1) do each and every incremental step while 2) taking the time to learn how it all hangs together AND 3) make sure that you run your code each time the tutorial prompts you... this will help ensure that you didn't miss something along the way. Good Luck!